# Find start point, int main()

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, program-entry-point

I am currently compiling a bought data stack in C. I use their own tool to compile it, using in the background gcc. I can pass flags and parameters to gcc as I see fit. I want to know, from which file is the main() used. That is, in the project, which file is the starting point. Is there any way to tell gcc to generate a list of files, or similar, given that I dont know from which file is main() being taken? Thank you.

Comment: There should only be one file containing the `main` function, or you would get a linker error. Where your tool put that we can't possibly know unless you tells us what tool it is.

Comment: Btw it's a very bad idea to try to mess around with undocumented details such as this.

Comment: why not: grep -rni "main" .   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disassemble the final executable to find the starting point. Although you have not provided any additional info to help you more. I'm using a sample code to demonstrate the process.

```
#include <stdio.h>

   int main() {
           printf("hello world\n");
           return 0;
   }
```

Now the object `main.o` has the following this

```
[root@s1 sf]# gcc -c main.c
[root@s1 sf]# nm main.o
0000000000000000 T main
                 U puts
```

You can see main is not initialized. Because it will changed in linking stage. Now after linking :

```
$gcc main.o
$nm a.out
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000600874 A _edata
0000000000600888 A _end
00000000004005b8 T _fini
0000000000400390 T _init
00000000004003e0 T _start
000000000040040c t call_gmon_start
0000000000600878 b completed.6347
0000000000600870 W data_start
0000000000600880 b dtor_idx.6349
00000000004004a0 t frame_dummy
00000000004004c4 T main
```

You see that main has a address now. But its still not final. Because this main will called by C runtime dynamically. you can see who will do the part of `U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5`:

```
[root@s1 sf]# ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff61de1000)  /* the linux system call interface */
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003c96000000) /* libc runime , this will invoke your main*/
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003c95c00000) /* dynamic loader */
```

Now you can verify this by viewing the disassembly :

```
00000000004003e0 <_start>:
..........
4003fd: 48 c7 c7 c4 04 40 00    mov    rdi,0x4004c4 /* address of start of main */
400404: e8 bf ff ff ff          call   4003c8 <__libc_start_main@plt> /* this will set up the environment for main, like pushing argc and argv to stack */
...........
```

If you don't have the source with you, then you can search in the executable for references to `libc_start_main` or `main` or `start` to see how your executable is initialized and starts the `main`.

Now all of these is done when linking is done with default linker script. Many big project will use its own linker script. If your project has custom linker script, then finding the start point will be different depending on the linker script used. There are projects which does not uses `glibc's` runtime. In that case, its still possible to find the start point by hacking the object files, library archives etc.

If your binary is `stripped` from symbols, then you have to actually rely on your assembler skill to find where it starts.

I've assumed that you don't have the source, that is the stack is distributed with some libraries and some header definitions only.(A common practice of commercial software vendors).

But if you have source with you, then its just too trivial. just `grep` your way through it. Some answers already pointed that out.

Answer (score 1):

From where `main()` is called is implementation-dependent -- using GCC, it will most likely be a stub object file in /usr/lib called `crt0.o` or `crt1.o` from which it is called. (this file contains the OS-dependent symbol which is automatically invoked by the kernel when your app is loaded into memory. On Linux and Mac OS X, this is called `start`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `objdump -t` to list symbols from object files. So assuming you are on Linux, and also assuming that the object files are still around somewhere, you can do this:

```
find -name '*.o' -print0 \
| xargs -0 objdump -t \
| awk '/\.o:/{f=$1} /\.text\.main/{print f, $6}'
```

This will print a list of object files and the references to `main` they contain. Usually there should be a simple map from object files to source files. If there are multiple object files containing that symbol, then it depends on which one of those actually got linked into the binary you're looking at, as there can be no more than one `main` per executable binary (except perhaps for some really exotic black magic).

After the application is linked and debugging symbols are stripped, there usually is no indication from which source file a specific function came. The exception to this are files which include the function names as string literals, e.g. using the `__FILE__` macro. Before stripping debugging symbols, you might use the debugger to obtain that information. If debugging symbols are included, that is.